# Retornar array com números maiores que o informado JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Preciso retornar com uma função todos os números de um *array* maiores do que o informado pelo usuário. Com a função que fiz aqui ele está retornando apenas o primeiro número do *array*, e preciso retornar o *array* completo.

```
function maiorNumero(array, numero)
{
   array = [70, 2, 9, 65, 5, -1, 0, 89, -5]
   numero= 7

  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
  {    
    if(array[i] > numero)
    {
      return array[i]
    }
  }
}

console.log(maiorNumero())
```

Essa função retorna 70. O retorno que preciso e 70, 9, 65, 89.

Comment: Já tentou utlizar Map, Reduce ou Filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem que criar um novo *array* temporário para incluir os itens que cumpram com a condição estabelecida. Não pode retornar um elemento só. Então estava no caminho certo, mas teve esse problema. Você vai adicionando os elementos no novo *array* apenas se o elemento atende o critério definido, e depois que passar por todos retorna o *array*. Pensa bem, se quer retornar vários elementos que atende o critério, a única forma é retornando um *array*, não pode retornar um elemento de um *array*.

Ainda tem outro problema que fez o código ficar esquisito. Você colocou os valores dos parâmetros dentro da função, isso deve ser argumentos passados para a função.

Eu fiz de uma forma próxima ao que fez, eu poderia ter usado um `for of` que seria mais adequado para o caso, mas mantive a linha que começou fazer. Também poderia fazer um filtro pronto, mas entendi que o exercício manda você fazer na mão através de uma função sua e não um filtro. E ficou assim:

```js
function maiorNumero(array, numero) {
    var novo = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) if (array[i] > numero) novo.push(array[i]);
    return novo;
}

console.log(maiorNumero([70, 2, 9, 65, 5, -1, 0, 89, -5], 7))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/GreatherThan.js).

Comment: muito obrigado, deu certinho aqui e bem mais simples que estava fazendo, vlw demais

Answer (score 2):

Javascript já trás consigo alguns métodos, e quando se trata de array você pode usar o método [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), que irá filtrar o array e retornar somente os elementos que verifiquem uma determinada condição, exemplo:

```js
var meuArray = [10, 50, 23, 70, 81, 90];
var arrayFiltrado = meuArray.filter(n => n > 70);

console.log(arrayFiltrado);
```

Neste caso você está filtrando o `meuArray` e para cada elemento deste array você verifica se o elemento `n` é maior do que o valor que você quiser e pode ser também uma variável, no exemplo o `arrayFiltrado` irá conter somente elementos de `meuArray` que são maiores do que 70.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar `filter()`. Isso cria uma novo array com todos os elementos que passam no teste implementado pela função fornecida.

```js
var array = [70, 2, 9, 65, 5, -1, 0, 89, -5];

    function numMaioresQue(arr, elem) {

      return arr.filter((item) => {
        return item > elem
      })
    }
    
console.log(numMaioresQue(array, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = [70, 2, 9, 65, 5, -1, 0, 89, -5];
var elem = 7;
    function numMaioresQue(arr, elem) {

      return arr.filter((item) => {
        return item > elem
      })
    }
    
console.log(numMaioresQue(array, elem))
```